# Password not accepted for newly created user under SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server-2008

I understand the limitation of a strong password choice under SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. I have a software that must use a specific password, which works on the Standard version of SQL Server; however, Enterprise is refusing to add the user because the password is weak and not fulfilling the requirements.

Is there any workaround for this? The server is for testing, so it is not a production server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the Local Security Policy, under Account Policies, Password Policy: "Password must meet complexity requierements" to `Disabled`

[alt text http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/4779/capturenty.png](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/4779/capturenty.png)